# JTable with complex formatting

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to make a JTable where each "cell" has a variety of separate data to display. I need to show, for each item, both as a percent of total and a dollar value, a target value, actual value, projected value, and the difference between any of the three. The attached image was done in Excel, but shows what I'm trying to produce in a JTable.
[image]

To make things even more interesting, other than the target and actual value rows, all other rows are selectable by the user at run time. As in they can choose what rows to display by selecting options within my program. I'll need to be able to customize cell shading, font and text format on a subcell-by-subcell basis, and I'll also need to vary borders, row heights and column widths throughout the table.

I've not started coding this yet as I'm contemplating different methods. I'm looking for feedback from others as to which approach to take, or if there are other options I should consider.

Option 1 - Just use a single JTable with a custom data model, but otherwise stay as close as possible to the default cell renderers and cell editors, and get fancy with boarders and formatting of each cell to mimic the intended look-n-feel. The data model would handle the translation from the row, column provided by the JTable and what item/value each cell actually corresponds to.

Option 2 - Use a JTable as the cell editor for each cell within the JTable (a table within a table).

Option 3 - Write my own custom cell renderer using a variety of labels and text fields.

Option 4 - Are there any pre-written components that offer the kind of flexibility I'm looking for I should consider?

Thoughts on the best approach to take appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Option 2A - Create separate `JTables` for each item and display the `JTables` in a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. If the data is larger that what can fit within the view, I presume it would work to put the panel into a scroll pane, set minimum widths for the rows and columns, and the scroll pane would scroll the view as needed?

Comment: You're showing four products in your example.  The four `JTables` are identical in structure for the four products.  If you want to display more products at a time, you should have specified so in your question.  But yes, you can put the `JPanel` in a `JScrollPane` to display more than four products.  However, you can't display thousands of products at one time.  It would be too large for a `JPanel` and too overwhelming for the user.  Maybe have another `JPanel` where you ask the user which four products they want to see now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going with Option 2A - thank, Gilbert. The code below and image attached are a proof-of-concept. Formatting is rudimentary at the moment but as a demonstration project it works.

```
package tableTest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;


/** Listener interface between data and TableDataModel to keep things in sync. */
interface DataNotifier {
    void update();
}

class Grid {

    JFrame frame;
    /** Data array in Row,Col array order */
    MyData[][] myData;
    Double totalValue = 1234567.89d;        // just a hack for demonstration purposes
    
    public Double getTotalValue() {
        return totalValue;
    }
    
    /** Constructor */
    public Grid() {
                
        MyData[][] myData1 = {
                {new MyData(0.060, 0.052, 0.058, "Red", "Square", this), new MyData(0.040, 0.038, 0.040, "Red", "Circle", this), new MyData(0.045, 0.045, 0.045, "Red", "Triangle", this), new MyData(0.080, 0.084, 0.081, "Red", "Octagon", this)},
                {new MyData(0.160, 0.142, 0.172, "Blue", "Square", this), new MyData(0.120, 0.135, 0.123, "Blue", "Circle", this), new MyData(0.000, 0.000, 0.000, "Blue", "Triangle", this), new MyData(0.060, 0.050, 0.052, "Blue", "Octagon", this)},
                {new MyData(0.080, 0.072, 0.079, "Green", "Square", this), new MyData(0.010, 0.023, 0.011, "Green", "Circle", this), new MyData(0.090, 0.120, 0.099, "Green", "Triangle", this), new MyData(0.110, 0.105, 0.110, "Green", "Octagon", this)},
                {new MyData(0.000, 0.000, 0.000, "Pink", "Square", this), new MyData(0.080, 0.065, 0.078, "Pink", "Circle", this), new MyData(0.030, 0.010, 0.028, "Pink", "Triangle", this), new MyData(0.035, 0.060, 0.024, "Pink", "Octagon", this)},
        };
        myData = myData1;
        
        initialize();
    }
    
    /** Initialize console */
    private void initialize() {
        
        final int ROW_HEIGHT = 24;
        
        frame = new JFrame("Grid Window");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        Font defaultFont = javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getFont("Label.font");
        
        // Add a control panel - allows us to initiate a change in the data.
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(controlPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        JButton action1 = new JButton("Increase Total Value");
        action1.addActionListener(this::action1ButtonPressed);
        controlPanel.add(action1);
        
        frame.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
        tablePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        
        for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                
                // cellPanel represents one of our "cells" in tabelPanel - it encloses the table, header and super-header
                JPanel cellPanel = new JPanel();
                cellPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                cellPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.black));
                
                // Create the super-header that is the title for each cell's data
                JLabel cellLabel = new JLabel(myData[r][c].getColor() + " " + myData[r][c].getShape());
                cellLabel.setFont(defaultFont.deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
                cellLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                cellLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(102, ROW_HEIGHT));
                cellLabel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(102, ROW_HEIGHT));
                // Add to cellPanel
                cellPanel.add(cellLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                
                // Create the table
                MyTableModel cellDataModel = new MyTableModel(myData[r][c], this);
                myData[r][c].setOurDataModel(cellDataModel);            // Gives myData a link to the TableModel for data change notifications
                MyCellRenderer cellRender = new MyCellRenderer();
                JTable cellTable = new JTable(cellDataModel);
                cellTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, cellRender);
                cellTable.getTableHeader().setMinimumSize(new Dimension(102, ROW_HEIGHT));
                cellTable.setRowHeight(ROW_HEIGHT);
                cellTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
                cellTable.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(102, ROW_HEIGHT));
                TableColumnModel tcm = cellTable.getColumnModel();
                tcm.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(120);
                tcm.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(80);
                tcm.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(80);
                tcm.getColumn(0).setMinWidth(120);
                tcm.getColumn(1).setMinWidth(80);
                tcm.getColumn(2).setMinWidth(80);
                cellTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
                
                // Since we're not putting the table into a scroll pane, we need to explicitly add the header
                // or it won't show. We'll use another panel for this.
                JPanel dataPanel = new JPanel();
                dataPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                // Add the header
                dataPanel.add(cellTable.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                // Add the table
                dataPanel.add(cellTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                
                // Add dataPanel to the cell panel
                cellPanel.add(dataPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                
                // Add cellPanel to the tablePlanel
                tablePanel.add(cellPanel);
                
            }
        }
        
        // We now have a panel with our home-made grid - add it to a scroll pane
        JScrollPane spTable = new JScrollPane(tablePanel);
        spTable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        spTable.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        
        frame.add(spTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
    }

    public void show() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    /** Pressing the button just increases TotalValue by 50% - just for demo reasons. */
    private void action1ButtonPressed(ActionEvent ae) {
        totalValue *= 1.5;
        System.out.println("New value = " + Double.toString(totalValue));
        updateData();
    }
    
    /** Initiate a data update
     * <p>
     * This tells each data object that the data has changed, which in turn tells each
     * TableModel which then tells the corresponding table.
     */
    private void updateData() {
        for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                myData[r][c].update();
            }
        }
    }
    
    /** Custom cell renderer */
    private class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        
        DecimalFormat currencyFormatter = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.00");
        DecimalFormat percentFormatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0%");

        protected MyCellRenderer() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {
            
            // First, adjust the value
            String newValue;
            if (column == 0) {
                newValue = (String) value;
            } else if (column == 1) {
                newValue = currencyFormatter.format(value);
            } else {
                newValue = percentFormatter.format(value);
            }
            
            // Call super
            JComponent c = (JComponent) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, newValue, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            JLabel cl = (JLabel) c;
            
            // Adjust formatting
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                // row header
                cl.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                cl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                break;
            case 1:
                // value column
                cl.setBackground(Color.white);
                cl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                break;
            case 2:
                cl.setBackground(Color.white);
                cl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                break;
            default:
                // Something we don't expect
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("column unexpected.");
            }
                        
            return cl;
        }
        
    }
    
    
    private class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel implements DataNotifier {
        
        /** Reference to the source data */
        MyData thisData;
        /** Reference to the console app - implemented for future use */
        Grid parent;
        private static final String[] rowNames = {"Target", "Actual", "Actual - Target", "Projected", "Projected - Target", "Projected - Actual"};
        private static final String[] columnNames = {"", "Value", "%"};

        /** Constructor */
        protected MyTableModel(MyData dataItem, Grid parent) {
            super();
            thisData = dataItem;
            this.parent = parent;
        }
        
        /** TableModel's end of the listenr interface */
        public void update() {
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }
        
        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rowNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columnNames[column];
        }
        
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            Double ret;
            Double mult;
            
            // Evaluate the column
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                // row header
                return rowNames[row];
            case 1:
                // value column
                mult = parent.getTotalValue();
                break;
            case 2:
                mult = 1d;
                break;
            default:
                // Something we don't expect
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("column greater than 2");
            }
            
            // Evaluate the row
            switch (row) {
            case 0:
                // Target
                ret = thisData.getTargetPct() * mult;
                break;
            case 1:
                // Actual
                ret = thisData.getActualPct() * mult;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Actual - Target
                ret = (thisData.getActualPct() - thisData.getTargetPct()) * mult;
                break;
            case 3:
                // Projected
                ret = thisData.getPlanPct() * mult;
                break;
            case 4:
                // Projected - Target
                ret = (thisData.getPlanPct() - thisData.getTargetPct()) * mult;
                break;
            case 5:
                // Projected - Actual
                ret = (thisData.getPlanPct() - thisData.getActualPct()) * mult;
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("row greater than our size");    
            }
            
            return ret;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
            super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
        }
    }
    
    /** Custom data object for our demo */
    private class MyData {
        
        Double pTarget;
        Double pActual;
        Double pPlan;
        String color;
        String shape;
        Grid parent;
        /** Data's end of the listener interface */
        DataNotifier ourDataModel;
        
        
        protected String getColor() {
            return color;
        }
        protected void setColor(String color) {
            this.color = color;
            update();
        }
        protected String getShape() {
            return shape;
        }
        protected void setShape(String shape) {
            this.shape = shape;
            update();
        }
        protected Double getTargetPct() {
            return pTarget;
        }
        protected void setTargetPct(Double pTarget) {
            this.pTarget = pTarget;
            update();
        }
        protected Double getActualPct() {
            return pActual;
        }
        protected void setActualPct(Double pActual) {
            this.pActual = pActual;
            update();
        }
        protected Double getPlanPct() {
            return pPlan;
        }
        protected void setPlanPct(Double pPlan) {
            this.pPlan = pPlan;
            update();
        }
        protected DataNotifier getOurDataModel() {
            return ourDataModel;
        }
        protected void setOurDataModel(DataNotifier ourDataModel) {
            this.ourDataModel = ourDataModel;
        }
        
        protected MyData(Double pTarget, Double pActual, Double pPlan, String color, String shape, Grid parent) {
            super();
            this.pTarget = pTarget;
            this.pActual = pActual;
            this.pPlan = pPlan;
            this.color = color;
            this.shape = shape;
            this.parent = parent;
        }
        
        /** Fire off an udpate to the listener */
        protected void update() {
            if (ourDataModel != null) ourDataModel.update();
        }
    }
}   // END OF GRID




public class TableTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Grid runwindow = new Grid();
                runwindow.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And an image

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1oI5.jpg)

[image]

Thanks.